# run-time error 429 on CreateObject

Tags: vbscript

i am getting run-time error 429, ActiveX error: cannot create object 'InternetExplorer.Application', while calling the below code from vbscript

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

i am running the code as non admin account. if run as admin, the code works fine. What could be the problem? Appreciate help on this

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as admin with this code :

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'Your rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: i need to run this on non admin account. i tried to run the code in powershell and got the below error  "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed". what does this mean?